# How do I add where condition?

Tags: sql, db2, subquery, where-clause

[image]

**I want to add a condition according to the returned result**

Comment: What about [**WHERE**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/where-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't reuse an alias defined in the `SELECT` clause in the `FROM` clause of the scope. You need to either repeat the expression, or use a subquery or CTE.

```
select dayofweek_iso(timestamp(mycol)) as mynewcol 
from mytable
where dayofweek_iso(timestamp(mycol)) = 1
```

Or:

```
select *
from (
    select dayofweek_iso(timestamp(mycol)) as mynewcol 
    from mytable
) t
where mynewcol = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Use your existing query as a subquery:

```
select * from (
<add your existing query in the screenshot here>
) t
where <add your conditions here>
```

Answer (score 0):

i think you should include your code in the post itself. A picture like this is quite unhandy.

[W3: SQL WHERE](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_where.asp)

as you can see here, just add your WHERE statement at the end:

```
SELECT * FROM XXX WHERE CONDITION
```

Answer (score 0):

Out of interest, since Db2 11.5, you can reference a column alias in a WHERE clause if using NPS (i.e. [Netezza compatibility](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_11.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.apdv.porting.doc/doc/c_compat_nz.html)) mode.

```
CREATE TABLE MYTABLE(MYCOL DATE)

SET SQL_COMPAT='NPS'

SELECT DAYOFWEEK_ISO(TIMESTAMP(MYCOL)) AS MYNEWCOL 
FROM MYTABLE
WHERE MYNEWCOL = 1
```

Still, this is best reserved for users migrating from Netezza as NPS mode changes some other things too.